# How to fix getSource() method to edit JButton Text in actionPerformed class?

Tags: java, swing, applet, jbutton, actionevent

I have to create a TicTacToe game in an applet for a school project in Ready to Program Java 1.42. In the actionPerformed class I would like to simply set/edit the text of the first square on the top left to "X". I have used setActionCommand() on the JButton and have called getActionCommand() in the actionPerformed class. However in my if statement, I use getSource() so I can refer to the object itself and set/edit the text. Can I not use getActionCommand() and getSource() together? Thank you.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.Applet;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class TicTacToe extends Applet implements ActionListener 
{
public void InitializeGame()
{

 setLayout(null);
 JButton Square1 = new JButton();
 Square1.setBackground(Color.white);
 Square1.setBounds(90,20,75,75);
 Square1.addActionListener(this);
 Square1.setActionCommand("s1");

 JButton Square2 = new JButton();
 Square2.setBackground(Color.white);
 Square2.setBounds(165,20,75,75);
 Square2.addActionListener(this);
 Square2.setActionCommand("s2");

 JButton Square3 = new JButton();
 Square3.setBackground(Color.white);
 Square3.setBounds(240,20,75,75);
 Square3.addActionListener(this);
 Square3.setActionCommand("s3");

 JButton Square4 = new JButton();
 Square4.setBackground(Color.white);
 Square4.setBounds(90,95,75,75);
 Square4.addActionListener(this);
 Square4.setActionCommand("s4");

 JButton Square5 = new JButton();
 Square5.setBackground(Color.white);
 Square5.setBounds(165,95,75,75);
 Square5.addActionListener(this);
 Square5.setActionCommand("s5");

 JButton Square6 = new JButton();
 Square6.setBackground(Color.white);
 Square6.setBounds(240,95,75,75);
 Square6.addActionListener(this);
 Square6.setActionCommand("s6");

 JButton Square7 = new JButton();
 Square7.setBackground(Color.white);
 Square7.setBounds(90,170,75,75);
 Square7.addActionListener(this);
 Square7.setActionCommand("s7");

 JButton Square8 = new JButton();
 Square8.setBackground(Color.white);
 Square8.setBounds(165,170,75,75);
 Square8.addActionListener(this);
 Square8.setActionCommand("s8");

 JButton Square9 = new JButton();
 Square9.setBackground(Color.white);
 Square9.setBounds(240,170,75,75);
 Square9.addActionListener(this);
 Square9.setActionCommand("s9");

 add(Square1);
 add(Square2);
 add(Square3);
 add(Square4);
 add(Square5);
 add(Square6);
 add(Square7);
 add(Square8);
 add(Square9);

}

public void init()
{
resize (400,300);
setBackground(Color.orange);

JButton Play = new JButton("Click to Play");                                 
Play.setBackground(Color.white);
Play.setForeground(Color.black);
Play.addActionListener(this);
add(Play);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)                         
{
removeAll();                                                       
setBackground(Color.pink);
InitializeGame();                                                   


if ( e.getActionCommand().equals( "s1" ) )
   {
   ((JButton)e.getSource()).setText("X");
   }

repaint(); 
} 

}
```

I expect to see "X" on the top left JButton. However the text does not appear when run.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). ..

Comment: 3) Learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 4) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! Most IDEs have a keyboard shortcut specifically for formatting code. 5) Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556). ..

Comment: 6) Don't mix Swing and AWT components. There is a `javax.swing.JApplet` for a Swing based applet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `actionPerformed()` method, you need to have `removeAll()`, `setBackground()` and `InitializeGame()` calls inside a `if` block like I have shown below:

Otherwise, the whole UI resets every time you click any button. (Because you have added this same `ActionListener` to all the buttons.)

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
  if (((JButton) e.getSource()).getText().equals("Click to Play")) {
    removeAll();
    setBackground(Color.pink);
    InitializeGame();
  }

  if ( e.getActionCommand().equals( "s1" ) )
  {
    ((JButton)e.getSource()).setText("X");
  }

  repaint();
}
```